# Missing shared library error in android

Tags: android, shared-libraries, manifest, logcat

I am working with a Google map and places oriented android project there it showing an error in log-cat while it compiling "missing shared library". I imported all the required library jar files to the project library folder but it still showing the same error in log-cat please any one help me to fix this

```
02-14 20:44:39.920: D/AndroidRuntime(323): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
02-14 20:44:39.920: D/AndroidRuntime(323): CheckJNI is ON
02-14 20:44:40.069: D/AndroidRuntime(323): --- registering native functions ---
02-14 20:44:40.909: D/dalvikvm(230): GC_EXPLICIT freed 165 objects / 11720 bytes in 151ms
02-14 20:44:41.510: D/PackageParser(58): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl40026.tmp
02-14 20:44:42.209: I/PackageManager(58): Removing non-system package:com.kodespider.parkon
02-14 20:44:42.209: I/ActivityManager(58): Force stopping package com.kodespider.parkon uid=10037
02-14 20:44:42.360: D/PackageManager(58): Scanning package com.kodespider.parkon
02-14 20:44:42.360: E/PackageManager(58): Package com.kodespider.parkon requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!
02-14 20:44:42.369: W/PackageManager(58): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.kodespider.parkon-2.apk
02-14 20:44:42.369: D/PackageParser(58): Scanning package: /data/app/com.kodespider.parkon-1.apk
02-14 20:44:42.399: D/PackageManager(58): Scanning package com.kodespider.parkon
02-14 20:44:42.410: I/ActivityManager(58): Force stopping package com.kodespider.parkon uid=10037
```

Comment: Are you using the correct API on your emulator? Or which device are you using?

Comment: i am using both android 2.2  and android 4.0 emulators both of it having google map API's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the build target to 'Google APIs' and not 'Android X.X' when creating your project.

Comment: what I said in the comments... glad you got it by the second time you read the same advice...